# Bootstrap 4 Dropdown menu when resized - color change

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

So as you can see the dropdown menu doesn't have any background color. How can i change this? Which class should i target so i can give a color to the dropdown menu?

Image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dh88.png

Comment: What is your html? Then we can see what class it is.

Comment: Default class for dropdown menu is .dropdown-menu . Try .dropdown-menu { background: your-color; }

Answer (score 0):

I am usign wordpress and this is the code in the header.php

```
       <nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top">

    <?php if ( 'container' == $container ) : ?>
    <div class="container">
    <?php endif; ?>
```

```
            <?php wp_nav_menu(
                array(
                    'theme_location'  => '',
                    'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                    'container_id'    => 'navbarNavDropdown',
                    'menu_class'      => 'navbar-nav ml-auto',
                    'fallback_cb'     => '',
                    'menu_id'         => 'main-menu',
                    'walker'          => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker(),
                )
            ); ?>

</div>
        </nav>
```